# Explanation of 70-persistent-net.rules script

Tags: networking, udev

I am a newbie in scripting language.I will like to understand a script that was written by someone else.Kindly explain to me what this line of script does:

```
IF=`cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules | grep $var | sed 's/^.*NAME=//' | tr -d '"'`
```

Here is what is in my 70-persistent-net.rules:

```
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:aa", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IF=`cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules | grep $var | sed 's/^.*NAME=//' | tr -d '"'`
```

## Short explanation

This line of script is going to either save the text `eth0` or `eth1` into the variable `IF`. It all depends on what is inside the variable `var`.

`cat` will display the contents of the file, `grep` will search and output the line that contains the text inside `var`, `sed` will delete everything from the beginning of the line until what comes after `NAME=`, `tr` deletes all quotations `"`.

The variable `var` most likely contains a MAC address, and the whole point of the line is to extract the interface of that MAC address. You `grep` for the line that contains the MAC address, and then you start deleting some stuff (using `sed` and `tr`) to end up with only the interface in the end.

## Long explanation

Here's a breakdown:

1. `` IF=`(somecommandhere)` ``: this means "save the output of `somecommandhere`" to a variable called `IF`.
2. `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`: display the contents of the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. At this stage, the output is:

   ```
   # PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

   # PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0 (e1000e)
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:aa", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
   ```
3. `|` this is a pipe symbol, which means "take the output of the command before the pipe, and make it the input of the command after the pipe". So the output of the `cat` command will be the input of the `grep` command. The second pipe will mean the output of the `grep` command will be the input of the `sed` command, and so on.
4. `grep $var`: `grep` is a tool that searches for something. `var` is a variable that is defined somewhere in your script, before this line.

   Let's say that the variable contains `00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9`. So `grep $var` means "search and output only the line that contains `00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9`. At this stage, the output is now:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
   ```
5. `sed 's/^.*NAME=//'`: `sed` is a command line tool that can manipulate the input, to delete or replace some text.

   The next part means uses this syntax: `'s/<replace this>/<with this>/'`.

   - Your `<replace this>` is `^.*NAME=`. This is a regular expression search pattern. This is used to "match" text. This expression means: match from the beginning of the line (`^`), match everything (`.*`) until `NAME=`. So basically this is what is matched (the bold text):

     ```
     SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
     ```
   - Your `<with this>` is nothing, so you're replacing the text you matched with nothing. This basically means you're deleting what you matched.

   At this stage, the output is this:

   ```
   "eth0"
   ```
6. `tr -d '"'`: `tr` is also a command line tool that can delete or translate text. This means delete all double quotes `"`. The output at this final stage is:

   ```
   eth0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a variable $var already defined in the script. We don't know what it is, but it is probably a MAC address.

The script line outputs the contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` through the "pipe" mechanism to the `grep` command. The output of this is: just the lines that contain the value of $var. This is assumed to be one line only. This one line is then treated by `sed`: it outputs the value that comes after `NAME=`. Finally, the `tr` command strips off the double quotes.

The result of this is either the value `eth0` or `eth1`, depending on the value of $var. This result is then assigned to the variable $IF. So the meaning of this line of script is: set $IF to the name of the interface with MAC address $var.

Comment: It was good of you to be so thorough. I thing The user would also benifit from a visit to tldp.org and looking around the various tutorials.